# Return from Hosting Controller to another controller from storyboard

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, storyboard

I have a project with `Storyboard` but now I'm migrating to `SwiftUI`.

I have a `Hosting Controller` that control del SwiftUI segment, but now I need to return from this to another controller from `Storyboard`.

Basically I can do this: `Storyboard (Controller 1)` -> `HostingController (SwiftUI)`.
So now y I need to return: `HostingController (SwiftUI)` -> `Storyboard (Controller 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use closures for this. I assume you are presenting the hosting controller like this?

```
let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

You can add a closure `dismissSelf`, inside your SwiftUI View struct:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var dismissSelf: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            dismissSelf?()
        }) {
            Text("Return")
        }
    }
}
```

This will call `dismissSelf` when the button is pressed. Now, you need to assign `dismissSelf` to a block of code that dismisses the `UIHostingController`. You can do it like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {    
    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        
        var viewController: UIViewController?
        
        let contentView = ContentView {
            /// set the closure (it's a trailing closure, so you don't need to put the `dismissSelf`)
            viewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        
        if let vc = viewController {
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    /// make the button
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 80, height: 40))
        button.setTitle("Present", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

There's one thing that's kind of *oof* about this. `viewController` will never be nil, but to avoid a force unwrap I put in an `if let`.

Result:

[image: Present button to present SwiftUI view, which contains a Return button to return back to the main screen]

Comment: That fine, but what I need is to go to another `ViewCotroller`, different to the first. Also comment that I call the `Hosting Controller` by a `IBSegueAction`.

Comment: @Playa can you show code for the `IBSegueAction`? Also, what is the navigation flow that you want? Do you want to *dismiss* the presenting Hosting Controller and replace the parent view the different view controller, or *present* that different view controller "on top" of the Hosting Controller?